# Android: How I get dialog object is showing in an activity

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have a question about the dialog in android.
I have an activity object and I want to know what dialog is showing on activity.
My problem is I want to show a snackbar when application has a warning message.
And I need show snackbar in activity. But from activity, when I get content view and pass to SnackBar (SnackBar.make(contentView, "text", duration). It show Snackbar below the dialog. I know we should get view from dialog to show Snackbar from dialog view.

Please help me for this case.

Regards,
Duc Trinh

Comment: why you want to show SnackBar from dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the params passed to make() method -

```
make (View view, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

**View: The view to find a parent from.** *`Snackbar` will find parent of view passed to show.*

You need to pass child element of `dialogView` in order to show `Snackbar` in Dialog. Consider passing -

```
Snackbar.make(mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.child_view), "SnackBar in Dialog", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
```

Answer (score -1):

you  have to pass the View of the Dialog to the SnackBar.

```
AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    // inflate the custom dialog view
    final View mDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
    // set the View for the AlertDialog
    mAlertDialogBuilder.setView(mDialogView);

    Button btn = (Button) mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Pass the mDialogView to the SnackBar
            Snackbar
                    .make(mDialogView, "SnackBar in Dialog", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = mAlertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```